# Translating months in Razor

Tags: razormediator

The Razor mediator allows for some formatting of datetime fields when they are rendered. For example,

```
@Metadata.EventDate.ToString("MMMM")
```

will render out the full text of the month. However, for translated sites I need to be able to select the language of the month it produces, ie. "janvier" instead of "January".

I've tried passing in a culture info indicator:

```
@{
var culture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
var month = Metadata.EventDate.ToString("MMMM", culture);
}
```

and doing the same in a single line:

```
@{
var month = Metadata.EventDate.ToString("MMMM", new CultureInfo("fr-FR"))
}
```

However neither option passes the validation in order to save my TBB. I also haven't been able to find any mention of this scenario in the Razor Mediator documentation.

Is there a way to define what language the month in a datetime will be displayed in?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It turns out that I was on the correct path, but had missed adding the proper using statement to my TBB. By inserting

```
@using System.Globalization;
```

at the top of my TBB I was able to use either of the methods that I tried originally without issue.